# Use child's inner class from parent template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I have a class A, which derives from a class template B.  A has an inner class which B needs to use, and if it can't then the design is moot.

```
template <typename child_t>
class B {
    typename child_t::inner_t& some_func();
};

class A : public B<A> {
public:
    class inner_t { };
};
```

When I attempt to do this, however, the compiler tells me that A does not have a member named inner_t.  My first guess was that this is because A is only partially defined, but this pattern is used all the time.  Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: It depends on the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RSahu I have a pattern that recurs often in my code - a number of classes have the same general set of functions that can easily be abstracted to a template.  I want to write a class that generates these functions, so that I don't have to write them over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you might be able to get around this problem.

1. Make `B` such that `A` doesn't have to derive from it.

   ```
   template <typename child_t>
   struct B1 {

       typedef typename child_t::inner_t inner_t;

       inner_t foo()
       {
          return inner_t();
       }
   };

   struct A1 
   {
      struct inner_t {};
   };
   ```

   Then, you can use it like:

   ```
   B1<A1> obj1;
   A1::inner_t inner = obj1.foo();
   ```
2. Don't count on the definition of `A` until you make a function call.

   ```
   template <typename child_t>
   struct B2 {

       void foo()
       {
          typedef typename child_t::inner_t inner_t;
          // Do something with inner_t()
       }
   };

   struct A2 : public B2<A2>
   {
      struct inner_t {};
   };
   ```

   Then, you can use it like:

   ```
   B2<A2> obj2;
   obj2.foo();
   ```

Comment: Alright, worked out the design to be more like #1.  Doesn't save as much typing but at least it's valid code!